Why does god has behaviour?
Yesterday I thought I will go to temple in the evening, but in the evening, before going to temple, I went to a grocery store in my vehicle.
While parking at the grocery store, I damaged my vehicle and cannot go to temple until it gets fixed next day.
Why does god gets angry on its people? Sometimes we see accidents happening and people dieing while going to temples also, so why does a god has behaviour if they are formless?
Karma is also an example like if a person did bad deeds, god will create problems to them, is it not because of angry behaviour?

If there's a negative event it is due to my own karma and anything positive is due to His mercy  - such a frame of mind will be needed if someone sincerely wishes to know the Supreme who is beyond the mundane ideas of form and formlessness.
